# How to get the actual code (not inside content) of an iframe element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have a look at this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/NTYcA/1/

```
var foo = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/A175-KHvfy4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

foo = $(foo); // turned into jquery object

alert( foo.html() ); // alerts nothing
alert( foo[0] );     // alerts [Object HTMLIFRAMELEMENT] but how can I get the actual iframe code as a string?
```

So how can I get the iframe code from the jquery object?

I literally want this:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/A175-KHvfy4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

without accessing the original var.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `outerHTML` in jQuery, so you'll have to do something like this:

```
var html = $('<div />').append(foo.clone()).html()
```